# Why text widget in flutter not displaying \t?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to format my text using `\t` & `\n` and want to display to user as a preview. The `\n` is working fine but I am having problem with 
`\t`.

I am using Text widget to display my string. My code is something like this.

```
Text("dog\n\t noun\n\t\t1. a domesticated carnivorous mammal that typically has a long snout, an acute sense of smell, non-retractable claws, and a barking, howling, or whining voice.\n\t\t2. tan unpleasant, contemptible, or wicked man."),
```

[image: as shown below]

As you can see `\t` is doing nothing .

Comment: What means 'having problem' exactly?

Comment: \t is not working as it should \n is creating new line but \t is doing nothing.

Comment: i've added a screenshot.